# The html5 appcache doesn't work?

Tags: html, .htaccess, html5-appcache

After following and copy paste from the internet instruction, here are my steps.

For the HTML with the name test-offline.html which reside in www.bla3x.com/folder_name/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<p>Hello... how are u ? </p>
<p><img src="uploads/baby.jpg" width="223" height="226"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The offline.appcache file I put it inside www.bla3x.com/folder_name/ and the offline.appcache is :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2017-03-24 v1.0.0
uploads/baby.jpg
test-offline.html

NETWORK:
upload_form.php

FALLBACK:
test-offline.html
```

I open a notepad then from the blank notepad I pasted this :

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

save as type : All Files (*.*) and name it ".htaccess" (without the apostrophe). Then I put this .htaccess file inside www.bla3x.com

The tree is :

```
www.bla3x.com/.htaccess
www.bla3x.com/folder_name/test-offline.html
www.bla3x.com/folder_name/upload_form.php
www.bla3x.com/folder_name/uploads/baby.jpg
```

So then I run it from desktop Firefox browser with the address : `www.bla3x.com/folder_name/test-offline.html`

After the page loaded, I disconnect the internet connection.
Refresh the page, but I get *"Problem loading page - Server not found - Firefox can't find the server at bla3x.com"*. So, the appcache doesn't work.

What did I do wrong ?
Thank you.

Comment: I'd find a different approach instead of debugging this one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thank you for your suggestion. Actually I do this, is not for a developing a website yet. Just curious and interested on how to implement the appcache. Anyway, thank you once again, ceejayoz.

Comment: Btw, please never mind of my question. I found out that I shouldn't include the "test-offline.html" in the Cache Manifest header. And also in the Fallback header it must not be the "test-offline.html" but different file. Thank you.